# What does the phrase "flutter shut" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

"His eyes **flutter shut** and he assumes his position of repose once more"

TFD for "Flutter"
5.  flutter - wink briefly; "bat one's eyelids"
... and one of the synonyms is "blink"

Does it mean that he closed his eyes after he blinked a couple of times in a fast manner or that closed his eyes and was moving his eyes tremulously afterward?

Comment: I find _flutter shut_ a rather odd expression; _flutter open_ is more usual, describing a person waking from sleep or unconsciousness whose eyelids flicker before staying open. This man evidently blinks before closing his eyes.

Comment: Can you give more context to the sentence? For example, the sentences before or after it.

Comment: Sentences before don't say anything useful for deciphering this. The person in question talks about a different topic. The first sentence when encountering this character says much more although i believe that it's implicit in the conversation that this character eventually opened his eyes. (I was questioning him about a murder btw it's a context from a video game :))                                                                                                                                     
"He raises an eyebrow as you approach but doesn't open his eyes "

Comment: Is  it something you read somewhere, or something you are writing?